# How can I really run a remote node?

Tags: monerod

Well, first of all, I can't keep monerod running on my VPS through an ssh session. When I close the ssh session it stops running.

Second question is do I need to open the port? Is it TCP or UDP port that needs to open? A quick command?

Seriously, the official guide is way too simple...it just tells to "simply run monerod" then you are running a node.

Thanks

Comment: Which guide? Re: ssh session, you need to daemonize using the --detach command or using screen . Google will help if that doesn't get you started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Method 1)  A one-time start of monerod

You can use 'screen' to keep it running when you log out.

Ubuntu: `apt-get install screen`

CentOS: `yum install screen`

```
screen monerod --rpc-bind-ip <your external IP address> --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind
```

Replace  with the IP address of your VPS.

When monerod is running inside of screen, you can press `Control-a-d` to detach from the screen session and return to the command line.  You use `screen -r` to reattach to the session.

## Method 2) Keep monerod running perpetually

Create a new blank file called `monerod-cron` and add the following line.  Be sure to enter the full path to your monerod binary and your external IP address.

`0 * * * * <full/path/to/monerod> --detach --rpc-bind-ip <your_ip> --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind`

Example:

`0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/monerod --detach --rpc-bind-ip 100.22.33.44 --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind`

Save the file and load it into your crontab by running `crontab monerod-cron`.  This will start monerod automatically every hour.  If monerod is already running, it will not start a second copy.

To view the monerod logfile:
`tail -f ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log`

To view the crontab logfile:
`tail -f /var/log/cron`

### Notes

Your firewall will need to accept incoming connections to TCP port 18089.

There's some more info at https://moneroworld.com/#nodes

Comment: Can you explain what does "--rpc-bind-ip" do? It seems it then restricts the node to be used just by myself? But I was thinking the ip address of my home computer should be the ip address not the vps ip address? What if I need the node to be used just by myself for the moment?

Comment: --rpc-bind-ip tells monerod which IP address to listen on for incoming connections.  If you want to restrict use to yourself, you could use a firewall on your VPS to only allow access from your (home) IP address.

Answer (score 2):

@apexio's answer should work fine, but you might want to create a systemd unit if that's what your distro uses.

[You can grab a pre-made systemd service spec from the source tree](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/raw/master/utils/systemd/monerod.service) if you didn't want to write it yourself. Copy that file to `/etc/systemd/system/monerod.service`.

After that you can load it in with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, start it with `sudo systemctl start monerod`, and make it start on reboot with `sudo systemctl enable monerod`.

You can check if the daemon is running with `sudo systemctl status monerod`, and check the logs with `sudo journalctl -u monerod.service`.

Here's the commands that you need to run to download the spec, load it, enable it and start it.

```
sudo curl -O /etc/systemd/system/monerod.service https://github.com/monero-project/monero/raw/master/utils/systemd/monerod.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable monerod
sudo systemctl start monerod
```

**ninja edit**: You probably want the daemon running as its own user, you can make one with `sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false monero`

> Second question is do I need to open the port? Is it TCP or UDP port that needs to open? A quick command?

Everything will work if you left it as-is, but it would help the network if you opened ports. I believe you need to open TCP port 18080, but you can configure that with the `--p2p-bind-port` parameter.

Comment: Hello. I lost at the port number. Why is @apexio suggesting 18089 while you are suggesting leaving as it is suffices, and then adding 18080? On the other hand, what port number should I put in my monero GUI client side that is trying to connect to the remote node? I just tried 18080 and 18089 but both failed (with IP address being my VPS IP). It says "couldn't connnet to the daemon ".